# 50% samples for same requests failing while execution of Jmeter script

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am executing Jmeter script and 50% samples for same request are failing. I am not sure why this is happening. Can someone help me to understand if this due to our server issue or because of my Jmeter script.
Edited: I found out that some samples are not able to extract regex from previous sample due to which failure is occurred. Now I wanted to know why some samples can extract regex and some cannot?

Comment: It is not possible to deduct the cause of failure only form your expression. Please provide more solid information like, what you have done so far, your Script configuration, etc

Comment: Do you have a load balancer on stage ? Find the error in log

Comment: @user7294900 I am not sure about that. I have to ask from some dev which are not available currently.

Comment: @Adnan I have configured my jmeter with 10 threads and while execution 5 samples are not able to extract regex which is why it is showing error. Is there a reason why 5 samples can extract regex and 5 cannot? On my local server script is running fine but when I try to run it on staging server then it fails for 50% of samples

Comment: Is failure request getting the response or not?, Adding constant timer can help, might be the case your server is not able to respond instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for you help. Issue is resolved when I updated user-agent in header manager for that particular request.